# piCore compatibility with python 3 on raspberry-pi 3 B+ model

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, tiny-core-linux

piCore version 9.3 is installed on a raspberry pi 3 B+ device.

The project requires python3 packages like `adafruit temperature library`, `pip`, `flask` for running a rest server, `gpio`, `some other python3 package`, etc...

Is Python3 and it's dependencies like above available in piCore??

Comment: Have you tried to do this? If not, what stops you?

Comment: I do not have a keyboard to attach to the pi board (I have old keyboard, its not usb), I have successfully installed the piCore in sd card and I have to tell someone if this can be achieved or not. 

I connect to raspberry pi(running official raspberry pi os) using ssh as respberrypi and my laptop are connected to same `wifi`, I have tested my project on raspberry-pi official os and it's working. I want to know if that project will work on `piOS or tiny core linux` as well. 

Thanks ...!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking to see if the 3B+ is supported by picore 9.3 (I do not think it is).  My tests are performed on a rPI-Zero-W.

To start:

- add a python3.6  [extension](http://tinycorelinux.net/9.x/armv6/tcz/) to picore from the command line:

  tce-load -wi python3.6.tcz
- create extensions for your python modules OR install pip3

When a change is made to the system it is NOT persistent (will not survive system reboot).  The backup command must be issued to facilitate persistence:

filetool.sh -b